# Equivalence of minor epicycle and eccentric

Tags: math-history, mathematical-astronomy

In epicycle-deferent astronomy, adding a second minor epicycle to account for observational discrepancies is mathematically equivalent to shifting the deferent into a so-called eccentric, or a circle with a center not at the Earth (see e.g. DeWitt (2010), *Worldviews*, p. 120), as was pointed out already by Hipparchus. Ptolemy famously chose the eccentric approach for the *Almagest*. I’m trying to wrap my head around how to geometrically prove the equivalence. Any ideas?[image: Minor epicycle]

Comment: Is it in connection with the double generation of the epicycloid ? See animation [here](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/epicycloid/epicycloid.shtml).

Comment: Fascinating! Though the idea I was after has to do with adding _yet another_ (minor) epicycle, and that this addition is supposed to have the same effect upon the movement as projected unto the outer circle of fixed stars by a line of sight from Earth as just shifting the original epicycloid by a distance equal to the diameter of the minor epicycle. I think it’s the earliest proof of an ”empirical equivalence” of two hypotheses. My question was obviously way too imprecise, I will update it.